# Inline-block not working

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/9FG4f/4/

I tried a different way to line up the labels and textfields in the form area along with the button horizontally, but the email label and txtfield is not aligned perfectly.

HTML

```
<div class="prefill2">
<h1>Need a Real Estate Expert?</h1>
<form class="action3" name="form1" method="POST" action="_sendmail.php" onSubmit="return CheckAll(this);">
    <div id="action3-fname">
        <label class="nick-3">Full Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="name2" name="full_name" />
    </div>
    <div id="action3-email">
        <label class="nick-4">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="text" class="email2" name="email">
    </div>
    <div id="action3-button">
        <input type="submit" class="btn2" value="JOIN NOW" name="submit">
    </div>
</form> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
 #action3-fname {
display:inline-block;
}
 #action3-email {
display:inline-block;
}
 #action3-button {
display:inline-block;
}

.action3 .name2 {
border:thin #999 solid; 
border-radius:5px; 
float:left; 
height:22px; 
margin-bottom:10px; 
margin-left: 1px;
margin-top: 8px;
padding: 4px;
width: 210px;
}
.action3 .email2 {
  border: thin #999 solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-left: 22px;
  margin-top: -8px;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 210px;
    }
.action3 .nick-3 {
color:#000000;
}
.action3 .nick-4 {
margin-left:23px;
color:#000000;
}
.action3 .btn2 {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ff8400;
  border: medium none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 140px;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: #action3-fname add with #action3-email {
display:inline-block;
}

Comment: Updated and that didnt align the div perfectly.

Comment: Updated - http://jsfiddle.net/9FG4f/4/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9FG4f/6/

Answer (score 3):

I'd get rid of the floats and the `margin-top`s. Like so:

```
.action3 .email2 {
  border: thin #999 solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-left: 22px;
  padding: 4px;
  width: 210px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/9FG4f/8/

*EDIT*
Updated with fiddle that closes all tags correctly and combines the first three lines of CSS into a class.

```
.actionClass {
   display:inline-block;
}

<div class="prefill2">
    <h1>Need a Real Estate Expert?</h1>
    <form class="action3" name="form1" method="POST" action="_sendmail.php" onSubmit="return CheckAll(this);">
        <div id="action3-fname" class="actionClass">
            <label class="nick-3">Full Name:</label><br />
            <input type="text" class="name2" name="full_name" />
        </div>
        <div id="action3-email" class="actionClass">
            <label class="nick-4">Email Address:</label><br />
            <input type="text" class="email2" name="email" />
        </div>
        <div id="action3-button" class="actionClass">
            <input type="submit" class="btn2" value="JOIN NOW" name="submit" />
        </div>
    </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct one. I'd also combine your `#action3-` ids at the top into a single class like `.action3`. It's cleaner.

Comment: Also, you can get rid of the `<br>`s and set `input, label { display: block; }`Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9FG4f/9/

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `<br>`, get rid of the `float`'s and it should all line up nicely.

```css
.action3 .name2 {
    border:thin #999 solid; 
    border-radius:5px; 
    /* float:left; <-- remove this */
    height:22px; 
    margin-bottom:10px; 
    margin-left: 1px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    padding: 4px;
    width: 210px;
}
```

**[Here is your updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9FG4f/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

I actually made them float left and corrected a couple margins. Button and everything lined up together.
 [Here's my updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/96XJN/)

```
#action3-fname {
float:left;
}
#action3-email {
float:left;
}
```